# Clicking an element on a tableau element on a website using selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, tableau-api

Trying to download data from this site: https://www.ccee.org.br/web/guest/precos/painel-precos

and am not able to select the download tab either by using xpath or id.  I don't think it is inside a frame but I'm unsure how to get selenium to recognize this button.  Is there something i need to select before trying to click that xpath?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Edge()

driver.get('https://www.ccee.org.br/web/guest/precos/painel-precos')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "tableauTabbedNavigation_tab_1"))).click()
```

Comment: your site can't be opened

Comment: That element is within an iframe. Inspect the page structure closer.

Comment: there's no such element with id `tableauTabbedNavigation_tab_1`, can you show us where exactly you want to click, perhaps add a screenshot